# Shark Cage Diving: What are the shark populations like in April at Oahu, Hawaii?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, adventure, diving, hawaii, pacific-ocean

In the spirit of Shark Week, I wish to ask a shark-travel question for an upcoming trip. I am hoping to do some **shark cage diving** while on a vacation to Hawaii next April, and I was wondering **which Hawaiian Island has the highest shark population** (or if it is more or less the same throughout)?

**Are certain species of sharks more highly concentrated at specific islands?** For instance, is one more likely to see bull sharks, tiger sharks, and hammerhead sharks in the waters around Oahu?

We are travelling in **April** (spending most time in **Oahu**), and are curious if that is shark-cage season? **When are the shark populations at their highest and when is underwater visibility at its best?**

*Note: I know shark-cage diving is controversial, but I heard there are companies out there that do not do illegal chumming to draw the sharks attention -- I'm not quite sure how they do it. But I'll make sure I go with an ethical company.*
[image]

[image]

Comment: I love the images! Are you sure you want to do this!? SCARY!!! :-O  And I certainly hope the first image is not a common occurrence and that no one was in the cage..... Yikes.... Be Safe! Happy Shark Week!